# error in redmine email notification via gmail

Tags: redmine, ubuntu-10.04

I setup redmine on Ubuntu 10.04.2

here is my email.yml:

```
# Outgoing email settings

production:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    tls:true
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    address: "smtp.gmail.com"
    port: "587"
    domain: "smtp.gmail.com"
    authentication: :plain
    user_name: "******@gmail.com"
    password: "*****"

development:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    tls:true
    address: "smtp.gmail.com"
    port: "587"
    domain: "smtp.gmail.com"
    authentication: :plain
    user_name: "******@gmail.com"
    password: "*****"
```

I start the redmine server as root,login redmine with admin
then **Administration>Settings>Email notifications**
and then I send the test mail by clicking the link at bottom

But i got this:
**An error occurred while sending mail (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)**

is there anyone who send email successfully via gmail?and please give me some suggestion

thanks advance!

-----------append1----------------

I copy the "**production:**" in the **config/email.yml** to "**# ==== SMTP server at using TLS (GMail)production:**" in the **/etc/redmine/default/configuration.yml** 
and also modify the "**# default configuration options for all environments**" in buttom of **configuration.yml**

It works!

[CLOSED]